# Manually invoking OnPropertyChanged for custom DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

So I've got a custom DependencyProperty like this:

```
public class PatientLookUp : TextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PatientProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Patient", typeof(Patient), typeof(PatientLookUp), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true });

    public Patient Patient
    {
        get { return (Patient)GetValue(PatientProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PatientProperty, value); }
    }

    //some logic for getting the Patient...
}
```

Edit: It is defined within a CustomControl. Another control using this CustomControl binds the Patient property and listens to it's changed event. The problem is, that I make some network request stuff and if I get a null Patient as a result, I still want to notify the other control that CustomControl has done it's stuff, even if the Patient hasn't really changed.
So now I want to invoke the PropertyChanged event manually. Is there any way to do this?

Hope you can help me, thanks.

Edit2: My XAML binding the Patient (shortened):

```
<Window Name="MyWindow">
    <Grid>
        <llc:PatientLookUp Patient="{Binding Patient}" MaxLength="10" Text="{Binding SocialSecurityNumber}" />
    </Grid>
<Window>
```

Now I need to notify the ViewModel of MyWindow in case the Patient object of the PatientLookUp has changed. The LookUp has a request logic fired on pressing the enter key. After the request has finished, I want to notify MyWindow's ViewModel, even if it couldn't find anyone and the value is still null.

Comment: `I need it to be invoked even if the value doesn't change.` - What you want to be invoked?

Comment: You can't do that. And it seems that you're mixing your business model in the UI, there shouldn't be any such property "Patient" in the UI at all. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: A UI control changing value shouldn't be indicating that an operation is complete. Use a command or routed event instead. As HighCore noted, you shouldn't be doing buisness logic in controls *anyways*.

Comment: @KevinSuppan Delete all your code and create proper ViewModels, I'm not sure what kind of "custom control" you're trying to create but usually custom controls (for example a Gauge) have primitive values as their data (such as a `double`) not complex business entities. You're mixing your UI with your business model and you will suffer for that.

Comment: @HighCore Well it is kind of a search box that gets a valid Patient value if found. I thought this to be something like the SelectedItem DependencyProperty of a ListBox, or is my thinking wrong?

Comment: @KevinSuppan "gets a valid Patient" is not a responsibility of the View, and ViewModel should fire that request and the actual "getting" should happen at the Data Model level. In any case the UI does not care at all about your business model, hence your Dependency Property is totally unneeded.

Comment: @HighCore maybe my edit explains what I want to accomplish. Thanks.

Comment: @KevinSuppan your edit still doesn't explain why would the UI care about your business model, and why would you create a DP to hold a reference to a business entity. I suggest you rethink your approach, you're mixing apples and oranges here. Also this: `I need to notify the ViewModel of MyWindow in case the Patient object of the PatientLookUp has changed` - you're doing it in the inverse manner. The ViewModel should acquire the Patient / whatever business entity and notify the View, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're deriving from a standard WPF `TextBox` and putting something that is totally out of place.

You're approaching this in very inconvenient manner.

Instead: use a regular TextBox, bind to a `PatientSearchViewModel.SearchString` and when that SearchString is changed, fire the search (from the ViewModel) and if found, set the `PatientSearchViewModel.Patient` property and `NotifyPropertyChange()` so that the UI is notified of the change.

You're going like this:

```
DataModel -> View -> ViewModel
```

while the most straightforward and convenient approach is this:

```
DataModel -> ViewModel -> View
```

Answer (score -1):

Your class needs to inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged interface and implement it's classes. Once that's done, you should be able to call OnPropertyChanged method on your property's set.

Inheriting INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Calling NotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public Patient Patient
{
    get { return (Patient)GetValue(PatientProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(PatientProperty, value);
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```